# apt-get update not working after vpn issue

Tags: apt, vpn, 20.04

By mistake, I tried the command sudo apt-get update while I was connected by vpn. However, I closed the vpn connection and now when I try to update the following error appears:

```
Hit:1 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease

Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]                                       
Ign:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                
Err:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release                                                                  
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]

Hit:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                  
Hit:6 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                               
Get:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [107 kB]                                                 
Get:8 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [16.6 kB]
Get:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [122 kB]
Get:11 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [208 B]
Get:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages [59.8 kB]
Get:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main Translation-en [44.6 kB]
Get:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [90.4 kB]
Get:15 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages [27.3 kB]
Get:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [68.3 kB]
Get:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe Translation-en [28.3 kB]
Get:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [136 kB]
Get:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons [66.0 kB]
Get:20 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [104 kB]
Get:21 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe DEP-11 128x128 Icons [264 kB]
Get:22 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata [532 B]
Reading package lists... Done       
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Is this a vpn issue or an IP issue? I am unable to figure it out. Please suggest.

Comment: The PPA (http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu) does not support focal/20.04, you should not have added it to your system, VPN is not your issue.

Comment: I have not manually added it, how do I fix this issue?

Comment: A new install has no 3rd party (PPA) added, they are not official repositories, and are added by a user on your system with `sudo` access. Check whomever has been granted `sudo` privileges on your system, as someone has added it post-install.